# openxml where clause for sql update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filter, flags

This is my xml

```
<root>
<children>
 <child id = "1">
  <description>This is child 1</description>
 </child>
 <child id = "2">
    <description>This is child 2</description>
 </child>
 <child id = "3">
    <description>This is child 3</description>
 </child>
</children>
</root>
```

I am trying to update a table named Child which has columns "ID" and "Description". The table already has the ID column values in it but the description is blank. I need to update this description against the ID from the above given xml file.

I tried doing a OPENXML with flag value as 2 (element-centric) and was able to retrieve all the descriptions. 
But am unaware as in how to retrieve descriptions based on the ID values, using a where clause in OPENXML.

The database I am using is SQL Server 2008.
(Also will OPENXML work for SQL Server 2005?)

This is wat I tried to do:

```
DECLARE @idoc int DECLARE @doc xml

select @doc= c from openrowset(bulk 'C:\Test.xml',single_blob) as temp(c)
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc output, @doc 

SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/root/children/child', 2)
  WITH (summary  varchar(1000)) descr 
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Thanks in advance
Nick

p.s: The structure of the xml cannot be changed. I need to work around with this constraint.

Comment: Your xml is invalid. The attributes need to be `<child id = "1">` with double quotes. Is that a typing mistake or does the "xml" really look like this?

Comment: i have made the changes. it was a typo. sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're on SQL Server 2005 or up and you're XML is stored in a variable called `@input`, you could try this:

```
declare @input XML 

set @input = '<root>
<children>
 <child id="1">
  <description>This is child 1</description>
 </child>
 <child id="2">
    <description>This is child 2</description>
 </child>
 <child id="3">
    <description>This is child 3</description>
 </child>
</children>
</root>'

;with GrabXML AS
(
    select
        child.value('@id', 'int') as 'ID',
        child.value('(description)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as 'Description'
    from
        @input.nodes('/root/children/child') as n(Child)
)
update dbo.Child
set description = g.Description
from GrabXML g
where dbo.Child.ID = g.ID
```

The `GrabXML` common table expression (CTE) parses and flattens the XML into rows and columns, and the following `UPDATE` statement uses those rows/columns to update the existing table.

**Update:** there are two possible problem points if your strings are longer than you expect:

first off, you might need to increase the length on the conversion from XML:

```
select
   child.value('@id', 'int') as 'ID',
   child.value('(description)[1]', 'varchar(999)') as 'Description'
```

and secondly, you need to check what length your column in the table `dbo.Child` is and truncate the length of the string extracted from the XML to not exceed the length of the database column:

```
update dbo.Child
set description = SUBSTRING(g.Description, 1, 575)
```

Here, you need to extract **at most** as many characters from the `g.Description` string as your database column `dbo.Child.description` allows.

Comment: thanks marc. but am loading the xml from a file. Edited my post. (This is wat i am trying to do)

Comment: @Nick - use Marc's code from the line `;with GrabXML` onwards, pre-pended with this part of your code `DECLARE @input xml select @input= c from openrowset(bulk 'C:\Test.xml',single_blob) as temp(c)`

Comment: The above solution by Marc worked. But it fails at times with the following error: "Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 2
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated." Is this probably due to huge amount of data that the @doc variable of type XML can't take. Wat could be the possible workaround for this?

Comment: @nick: some column in your target table obviously is too short for the data you're importing...